# Insert function is called more than once

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I have a website where people send each other messages
Recently I noticed that sometimes the same message is sent more than once
For example, a message is sent four times within three seconds or twice within a second
I do not understand how this could happen, once the user clicks on the button that sends the message
So all the window switches and a message showup saying "the mail is sent successfully."
I checked that if the user refreshes the page after it sends a message, then really the message is sent again.
But I do not think that's the case, becouse the message is sent twice within one second.
I am writing in vb.net and using mysql data base.
Maybe it's related to the queue for the db, i do not know.
I need to know where to look
Hope for your help

Here's the code:

Function calls:
Call GlobalFunction.update_mailbox_table(user_id, receiverId, txtMessage.Text, private_picture)

the insert function

```
Public Shared Sub update_mailbox_table(ByVal user_id As Integer, ByVal receiverId As Integer, ByVal message As String, ByVal privatePicture As Integer)

    ' update mailbox table
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mysql_ConnString").ConnectionString
    Using mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Dim sqlCommand As String = "INSERT INTO mailbox_table (FromId,Message,ToId,SendingDate,MsgStatus,PrivatePicture) VALUES (@FromId,@Message,@ToId,@SendingDate,@MsgStatus,@PrivatePicture)"
        Dim mysqlcmd As New MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, mysqlconn)
        Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromId", user_id)
            mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", message)
            mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToId", receiverId)
            mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendingDate", Date.Now)
            mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MsgStatus", 0)
            mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrivatePicture", privatePicture)
            mysqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            sendToLog(ex, "problem to update mailbox table")
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: None of your questions have accepted answers, when someone gives you the correct answer please click the checkmark next to their name so that they receive credit for the answer and also upvote the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the database code, my psychic debug power tells me that your user double of quad clicks on your submit button.

Comment: Don't forget the ever popular tri-clicks.

Comment: but i have message that shopup in db 4 times within 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Javascript to show the message client side (i.e. actually *before* the message has been sent), or are you showing the message when the page reloads after sending the message?

If you are not hiding the button using client script, the user can easily click several times before the page reloads. Each click will send a request to the server, but the browser only shows the response for the last click.